# How to implement DeliveryReceiptManager in Android aSmack

Tags: android, asmack

I'm trying to get message delivery notification in Android (using aSmack library).
Found out that I need to use the DeliveryReceiptManager class, however, when I try to import it into my project 
(`import org.jivesoftware.smackx.receipts.DeliveryReceiptManager;`) 
I get the error that this can not be resolved.
However, I can import the DeliveryReceiptProvider class into project just fine.
Can this be used to receive delivery confirmation of sent messages?
Any sample code is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You Should look to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458018/delivery-receipt-requests-not-working-for-xmpp-android-asmack

Comment: I am trying to add DeliveryReceiptManager to get delivery report of sent messages. i used this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36EZWyRnHQxWUVb6R8Zus5s) of yours, but its giving error on *addReceiptReceivedListener* i.e *The method addReceiptReceivedListener(new DeliveryReceiptManager.ReceiptReceivedListener(){}) is undefined for the type DeliveryReceiptManager* Can you please help ? @CristianG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue, then used the latest jar from [here](http://asmack.freakempire.de/)

`deliveryreceiptmanager` was visible now.

Comment: Can you specify the link ?

Comment: what do you mean by that? that link in my answer has all the jars available to download. DeliveryReceiptManager class was not visible in some old jars.

Comment: I am trying to add DeliveryReceiptManager to get delivery report of sent messages. i used this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36EZWyRnHQxWUVb6R8Zus5s) of yours, but its giving error on *addReceiptReceivedListener* i.e *The method addReceiptReceivedListener(new DeliveryReceiptManager.ReceiptReceivedListener(){}) is undefined for the type DeliveryReceiptManager* Can you please help ? @Farhan

Comment: nawab saab, give me a little more info, like which library u are using? and which code of mine u r using? i never wrote my code here :^)